# jquery: RadiobuttonGroup check if element was selected before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radiobuttonGroup and I want to do an action, if the radiobutton, which is clicked, was selected before the click was triggered. Is this possible or do I have to store the current clicked value in a hidden field and then compare with the new clicked radio?
The reaseon why I need to know this is, that I want to deselect all radio's when the radio is clicked again.

```
<input type="radio" id="star6" name="rating" class="cat" value="6"/>
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" class="cat" value="5"/>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" class="cat" value="4"/>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" class="cat" value="3" >
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" class="cat" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" class="cat" value="1"/>
```

When I made this, the radiobutton IS ALWAYS selected with my if-clause:

```
$('.cat').on('select', function() {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
              //deselect all radio's
            }
        });
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a hidden field to do it... you can just assign a class to the inputs on click.

Here is a functional sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/o8z4monj/3/

```
$('.cat').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $('.cat').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
        });
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! It works! The only thing I need to do was to set $(this).removeClass('clicked'); in the each loop, otherwise, the element can never be clicked again! THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!